# Symbol for Intersection of sets with mutliple sublines?

Tags: align

[image]

I want to realize this but i couldn't manage. I tried something like

```
\begin{align*}
K:=\cap_{K \subset L\\ sth} 
\end{align*}
```

but that didn't do it it just threw the "sth" into a whole new row.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome t TeX.SX! You can highlight code in your post using back-ticks. To highlight code-blocks, either indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui. Also, rather posting code snippets please give give acomplete  [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what packages etc you are using. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. A MWE will often clarify your problem and it makes it much easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\substack` from the [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package:

[image]

Here's the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

  \begin{align*}
    K(\lambda):=\bigcap_{\substack{K \subset L\\L \text{ sth}\\\chi\in L}} L
  \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That works thank you! Just a little problem occured. My compiler (Sharelatex) complains about an undefined control sequence. But it seems like it does anything as it should. Do i need to fix something then, or leave it as it is since it works? (amsmath is loaded, but also a couple of other packets; big project)

Comment: @TomGöbel Hard to say if you don't tell me what the error message says! I just checked the code above in sharelatex and it compiled without errors so the problem is probably somewhere else in your document.